# ruby on rails AWS-S3 list files in a bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a select box the I wish to fill with filenames from a clients S3 bucket.
In my controller I set the variable as this:

```
@files = AWS::S3::Bucket.find("clientsbucket").objects
```

which when called in the view as `options_for_select(@files)` gives a list of objects but in the format of `<AWS::S3::Object:0x4f9e5b8>`, `<AWS::S3::Object:0x4f9e5a0>` etc 
For the life of me I cant figure out how to list the filename instead of this object info?

Any help muchly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, access the key property of the each object in the view!
key property is the entire path to the file in the bucket.

```
objects.each do |object|
  = object.key
```

Even though the AWS SDK Documentation isn't as informative try and dig around..
Use the as_tree method on the objects so you can get the specific data you want.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Tree.html

**Good luck!!**